# Angular Service Worker registration with Promise in environment

Tags: angular, promise, service-worker

Angular 8 projekt. I have Promise in environment file:

```
export const environment:any = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', './assets/env/environment.json');
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }
    else {
      reject('Cannot load configuration...');``
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
});
```

This Promise returns correct value `production=false` or `production=true`. At the same time Service Worker register correctly if I put there `true` or `false`:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register("ngsw-worker.js", {
   enabled: true    // or false
})
```

Registration doesn't work if I put `enabled: environment.production` or even `enabled: environment.then(env => env.production)`.

How can I register Service Worker depend on result of this Promise in environment file?

Comment: You need to move the `ServiceWorkerModule.register(…)` call inside the `then` callback.

Comment: Unfortunately this registration is inside `imports: []` in the `app.module.ts`, so it throw the error `Unhandled Promise rejection: Unexpected value '[object Promise]' imported by the module 'AppModule' ` when I move it into `then` callback. I have tried catch this promise outside `@NgModule` decorator but still doesn't work. It looks that such kind of "resolver" of `app.modules.ts` will help if it exist.

Comment: I have manage. My solution isn't direct answer for the question, so I leave it only in this comment. I have bypassed the Promise by simply import the same json file which is call by Promise: `import * as JsonEnvironment from "../assets/env/environment.json";` (it is required to set `"resolveJsonModule": true` flag in `tsconfig.json` file). Unfortunately I have to leave this Promise for other functions (I don't know why somebody make it in that way), so I have the same thing made twice.